# Why is this jquery presence check not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so that on focus the colour changes to orange for pending, and then when something is entered it becomes valid and therefore turns green.

However, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    $('#listingnewform').focus( function(){
  $('#listingnewform').css("border-bottom", "1px solid #C0AE31");
});

$('#listingnewform').blur( function(){
  if ($('#listingnewforum').length) {
    $('#listingnewform').css("border-bottom", "10px solid #fff");
  }
  else{

  };
});
```

Any help massively appreciated :)

Comment: Tip: Always use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) when posting javascript questions, it makes so much easier for others to actually see the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#listingnewform')
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('focused');
    })
    .keyup(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() ) {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('valid');
        };
    });
```

Than control styles via css:

```
#listingnewform.focused {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C0AE31;
}
#listingnewform.valid {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

See it in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/bjc2z20d/)

Answer (score 0):

**1st**:use (this) to reference to your class or id 
**2nd**:

```
$('#listingnewform')
.click(function() {
    // when click check input empty or not
    // if empty change border-bottom to yellow
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $(this).css('border-bottom','3px solid yellow');
    }
})
// when user start typing change border-bottom to red
.keydown(function() {
    $(this).css('border-bottom','3px solid red');
})
// when keyup check for valid name and change border-bottom to green
.keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "admin"){
    $(this).css('border-bottom','3px solid green');
    }
})
// when focusout return border-bottom to input border
.focusout(function() {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid black'); 
});
```

Here's [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/nra4nd39/2/)